# Get average length of one string field in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I gave tons of Json files stored in ES as follow:

```
{
    {
        "_id": "asd123",
        "lang": "en",
        "content": "This is a dog."
    },
    {
        "_id": "asd1",
        "lang": "de",
        "content": "Was ist das?"
    },
    ......
}
```

Each language has more than one documents.
I would like to get aggregated statistics: the average content character length of each language, like:

```
"en": 26.32
"de": 23.51
...
```

What ES query should I use?

Comment: Have you tried anything at your end ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the same fields as you provided above, based on this I did a sub aggregation. Using terms aggregation and string stats.

Links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-string-stats-aggregation.html

Here are the data I ingested in an index:

"lang" : "en",
"content" : "This is a dog."

"lang" : "en",
"content" : "This is a cat."

"lang" : "de",
"content" : "Was ist das?"

"lang" : "en",
"content" : "My name is John Smith"

Both lang and content were mapped as a text fields.

The following query was used:

```
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "language_split": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "lang.keyword"
    },
    "aggs": {
      "length_of_each_lang": {
        "string_stats": {
          "field": "content.keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "language_split" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "en",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "length_of_each_lang" : {
          "count" : 3,
          "min_length" : 14,
          "max_length" : 21,
          "avg_length" : 16.333333333333332,
          "entropy" : 3.8118793047756703
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "de",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "length_of_each_lang" : {
          "count" : 1,
          "min_length" : 12,
          "max_length" : 12,
          "avg_length" : 12.0,
          "entropy" : 2.8553885422075336
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I think the `avg_length` is what you need.

Note: This function is available as from version 7.6+:
However, you might consider to re do the mapping as content can't be considered as "keyword".

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-metrics-string-stats-aggregation.html

If it is possible to do an `_update_by_query` so as you can add a new field to the current mapping, then I suggest you use this pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/add-length
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ctx.content_length = ctx.content.length();
        """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then run the following command: `POST avg-length/_update_by_query?pipeline=add-length`

Note: The pipeline will add a field name `content_length` to the current index, with the respective value being the length of each `content` per document

When the pipeline is successful, the following aggregations might work in this case:

```
GET avg-length/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "isolate_lang": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "lang.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "average_length_per_lang": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "content_length"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The response will be:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "isolate_lang" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "en",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "average_length_per_lang" : {
          "value" : 16.333333333333332
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "de",
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "average_length_per_lang" : {
          "value" : 12.0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I get "type": "named_object_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "[24:25] unable to parse BaseAggregationBuilder with name [string_stats]: parser not found""

Comment: @Munichong, which version of elasticseach to you use ?

Comment: I am sorry, I corrected the post to mention the ES version. As @Jaycreation pointed out, I didn't take into account that older version prior of 7.6 doesn't have this function. If you need to do this with older versions, you can use a script. However, you can do it at Ingestion time and not at querying time. The reason is that the performance can be highly affected.